# What was Stree?

Tags: plot-explanation, stree

In the movie [Stree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stree_(2018_film)), what was Stree?

There is a reference to a story that claims that she was just a woman who was killed. And now her **ghost** haunts the town that killed her.

There are also references to her ponytail being the source of her powers indicating that she is a **witch** of sorts.

So is Stree a ghost or a witch?

Answer (score 7):

The other answer described it nicely but if you go with the specific detail given in the film itself then she is pretty similar to a known south Asian folklore entity called [Dayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dayan_(witch)):

> The primary source of a Daayan's power is her **long plaited hair** or ("choti"), she is described as having long and monstrous black nails, and **feet that face backward**.

Matching with the film details. Long ponytail as a source of power and feet backward are also shown in films like [Ek Thi Daayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ek_Thi_Daayan) and many other TV shows /films etc which portray Dayan.

The only issue was Dayan is the evil spirit by birth but Stree was vengeful spirit similar to [Churel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churel).

So I will say she is Dayan with the origin more similar to Churel then Dayan.

Also to be noted here film was inspired by [Nale Ba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nale_Ba) popular folklore legend about a witch.

Comment: Can we say a "Dayan" is a ghost with powers in braid?

Comment: @naive Dayan are not ghosts but evil entity, more near term will be witch.

Comment: Is a Dayan a dead woman? Or a living woman with black magic and stuff?

Comment: @naive in general no but in film yes as I said in my answer

Comment: thanks for the links @AnkitSharma .. looks like the concept of Succubus (another variation of a witch) is also thrown into what Stree is because of the sexual element.

Answer (score 5):

## Stree is a ghost with powers in braid.

From Wikipedia:

> The plot is based on the Indian folk legend about **a female spirit** who attacks men at night if they are alone and only leaves their clothes behind. The residents of a town named Chanderi, Bhopal believe in the **spirit of an angry woman**, referred to as "Stree", who stalks men and whisks them away during the four days of a festival every year, causing many disappearances.

For the question:

> There are also references to her ponytail being the source of her powers indicating that she is a witch of sorts.

Some noun [meanings of witch:](https://www.google.com/search?q=witch&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN846IN846&oq=witch&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1482j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

1) a woman thought to have magic powers, especially evil ones, popularly depicted as wearing a black cloak and pointed hat and flying on a broomstick.

2) an ugly or unpleasant woman.

*synonyms:  hag, crone, harpy, harridan, termagant, she-devil;*

So, we can say that ***Stree is a ghost with powers in braid.***

Comment: isn't the power in the ponytail associated to a witch and not a ghost? Isn't that the popular mythical element?

Comment: Yes true. But, that doesn't mean that a ghost cannot have powers in the braid.

Comment: I will not call her ghost as that's too general term and didn;t describe her exactly